# pass a variable into a string ksh

Tags: bash, unix, ksh

how do you pass a global variable into a string inside a function?

I have the following code that works for the most part:

```
td_query () { bteq << EOF |grep '^>' |sed -e "s/^>/;/g" 
$(cat $HOME/.tdlogon)
    DATABASE $schemaName;
     .set width 10000;
      .set titledashes off;
    $1
.LOGOFF;
.QUIT;
.EXIT
EOF
}

rqstID="1357"

echo $(td_query "select  '>'||'UPDATE schema.SEGN_$rqstID_PRCSS_TBL SET POPN_LVL_EXCLN ='||a.CODE_ID||' WHERE ' || b.SQL_FILE_NM ||' AND POPN_LVL_EXCLN IS NULL'
        FROM SE_POPN_EXCLSN a
        INNER JOIN SE_CODE_LIB b
        ON
        a.CODE_ID = b.CODE_ID;")
```

but the results come back:

```
UPDATE schema.SEGN_ SET POPN_LVL_EXCLN = 1002 WHERE MR_IND = 'Y'
```

missing this:

```
$rqstID_PRCSS_TBL
```

it should be:

```
UPDATE schema.SEGN_1357_PRCSS_TBL SET POPN_LVL_EXCLN = 1002 WHERE MR_IND = 'Y'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`_` is a legal character in a shell variable. The shell is trying to find a variable by the name of `$rqstID_PRCSS_TBL` and getting an empty string. (That's why `_PRCSS_TBL` is disappearing from your output.)

You need to tell the shell where the variable name ends: `schema.SEGN_${rqstID}_PRCSS_TBL`